# string ternary operator syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, syntax, operator-keyword

I'm doing this in my code:

```
destImp.Cap = (addr.location.postcode != "?") ? addr.location.postcode : null;
destImp.Civico = (addr.location.street != "?") ? addr.location.street : null;
destImp.Localita = (addr.location.city != "?") ? addr.location.city : null;
destImp.Indirizzo = (addr.location.street != "?") ? addr.location.street : null;
```

But it's cumbersome and redundant. There is a batter way to achieve the same result but with a better syntax?

Comment: You could define an extension method on `string`, called say `NullIf()` that wraps up this test.

Comment: You can at least write a method (or a local lambda) that does this.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent a `?` to be in these fields at all? What if a street is called `?` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create an extension method:

```
public static string NullIf(this string str, string nullMarker)
{
   return str == nullMarker ? null : str;
}
```

then you can do:

```
destImp.Cap = addr.location.postcode.NullIf("?");
...
```